# How to avoid including "-D_BSD_SOURCE" in compile statement every time the code is compiled?

Tags: c, strdup

To avoid a whole bunch of `strdup` errors, I have to always include `-D_BSD_SOURCE` in my compile statement. Is there a way I can somehow include this in my `.c` file and never include it in my compile statement again.

Comment: I don't think `strdup` requires `_BSD_SOURCE`, does it?

Comment: @immibis: It requires *some* feature test macro. It's not defined by ISO C. The man page on my system lists half a dozen relevant macros.

Comment: In many ways, you're not giving us very much context to work with.  What platform are you on?  Which compiler are you using?  Which options (other than `-D_BSD_SOURCE`) are you using?  Since `strdup()` is part of POSIX, you can often get what you want by `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700` or something similar, or the equivalent in a header file.  You can often avoid the problem by compiling with GCC (or clang) and `-std=gnu11` instead of `-std=c11`. I use a header `posixver.h` which defines `_XOPEN_SOURCE` and include that first. YMMV — but we'd be able to help you better if you gave us more information.

Comment: Note that on some platforms, `-D_GNU_SOURCE` will work as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the top of your .c file, *before* the includes, put this:

```
#define _BSD_SOURCE
```

Comment: Wierd, but I am still getting the implicit declaration warnings.

Comment: **before** includes, i think

Comment: This gets more complicated if precompiled headers are in use